# Setup Android intent so all existing activities is removed from backstack before a new one is created

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

What I want to achieve is starting my activity from two different locations, and depending on location my activity is started from the user interface got set up a bit different. The best solution for me would be to dismiss any existing activities to ensure `onCreate()` always is called, this is where I would like to setup my user interface.

I have tried a different solutions to achieve this. To start with I've tried change `launchMode`in `Android Manifest` to `android:launchMode="singleTask"` and `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` even though it seems to only keep one task or instance in memory at time it will not run `onCreate()` if there are a activity already, in that case `onNewIntent()`will be executed. And this is not exactly what I want.
Another way to achieve this would be to set `android:history="false"` but this is not an option as It's needed for other funtionality in my application.

I have also tried to set different flags to the `Inten`starting my activity. An Intent setup like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

fired of as a `PendingIntent` seems like to be a sure way of getting `onCreate()`called everytime, however the flags doesn't seem to do what they describe. If I'm in ma activity and press Home button and then start my activity again, then `onCreate()` is called as it should, but if I then press back button then it navigates to the activity I pressed Home button from, so the flags doesn't seem to ensure activity to be single on top neither clear top.

To be honest I'm really stuck at this one, a simple problem, but the solution became a nightmare. You got to be able to achieve this by setting up the intents correctly, or?

Comment: Would it work for you if you simply hide/show the UI you want on receiving the intent?

Comment: @StoneBird There's a fragment that should be switched, so yeah, it would be possible. But I think it's more cleaner to have all UI build up within `onCreate()` and this must be possible somehow to achieve.

Comment: why don't you want to use onNewIntent?

Comment: @pskink as I said in my comment earlier, I would like to do all UI handling in onCreate() as it becomes much cleaner that way, also I think all building of ui, fetching data and other meaty setup should be done in onCreate(). Can't really see why it should be so hard to set up an intent that removes any existing activities from the backstack and creating a new one. To me this seems to be something that's not that unusual beaviour, but then again fiddling with intents, flags and manifest properties is always  much more complicated then you think when start out working with it.

Comment: you can call the same code in onCreate and onNewIntent,  whats the problem?

Comment: @Robert in that case you will have to call ```finish()``` explicitly so that ```onDestroy()``` will be called. It's not exactly a symmetry to ```onCreate()``` but I believe it would make the system call ```onCreate()``` when it's starting the app again. Please try, but there is no guarantee from me.

Comment: @pskink, yea sure I can call the same code in `onCreate()` and `onNewIntent()`, but I would prefer any existing activities to be removed from the backstack and a new one created upon `startActivity()`, and this would be possible I think with `Intent` flags but I havn't got it to work. So for now calling same code in `onNewIntent()`as in `onCreate()` is not a solution for now.

Comment: @StoneBird, I've tried to explicitly call `finish()` in `onUserLeaveHint()` and even though it isn't that clean solution it works as it should, almost. Because the user has a possibility to select a file in my activity using file chooser intent, and when user is forwarded to the android file chooser mechanism then the user is seen as leaving the activity and the activity is destroyed. This causes trouble when the user has picked a file and should come back to the activity with a result, then the activity doesn't exist anymore and this functionality is broken.

Comment: @pskink, @stonebird, I ended up using `onNewIntent()` and `android:launchMode="singleTask"`, this works fine and after I refactorized the functionality that builds the UI to fit both `onCreate()` and `onNewIntent()` it turned out to be a pretty nice solution actually.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

so backstack will be cleared, but `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` is introduced in `api 11`, so if you want to use it in lower api just add `android-support-v7-appcompat` to your project and use like this:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

if you want to all activities closed without animation add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION` .

Comment: this didn't work as expected either. Even though the activity is always created when starting activity, the backstack seems to not be cleared. Example, if I start my activity from location1 then presses home button and start my activity from location2. When I press back at this point then it moves back to activity started from location1.

Comment: Combine this with  `android:launchMode="singleTask" ` or/and `android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"` , may be it work. anyway what do you mean by 'location1' and 'location2' specially when you press home?

Comment: Okey, will try it later today and see how it goes, even though I solved it another way(see comments above) this is interesting to know. With location1 and 2 I mean if I start my activity from my applications launcher icon or if I start it from my widget.